# Sum specific list items and assign the sum value into a different list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Alright, here's my scenario :

I have 2 custom lists : **Orders and Items**. The **Items list** contains a field **Description** (text) and a **Amount Per Item** field (calculated). The **Orders list** contains a **Total amount** field and a **Items** field (lookup on the description field in items which allows multiple values selection).

Here's a more visual explanation :

> 1. **Orders**
>
>    - Total amount
>    - Items (lookup on the description field in items which allows multiple values selection)
> 2. **Items**
>
>    - Description (text)
>    - Amount per Item

I would like to do the **sum** of the **Amount per Item** field of the selected items **from the Items lookup field from Orders** and put the value of the sum in the **total amount field in Orders**

Any suggestions? Is it possible to do this in SharePoint 2010 without code? If not, could you show what the code would look like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
OrderList.Total = OrderList.Items.Sum(item => item.AmountPerItem);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that would do the sum of all the items of the Amount Per Item in the Items list. What I need is do the sum of specific items that have been selected in the Items field in the Orders list.

Comment: where you have the selected list of items?

Comment: The selected item are selected by a lookup field (which points to the description field in Items) in Orders.

Comment: I don't have any. I don't have access to code right now. That's why I was asking if it could be done without code. If it's possible without it, it would save me time.